# radio button will not bind properly Angular

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following view

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
 <td>
<input type="radio" name="{{item.GroupName}}"  data-ng-value="   {{item.BooleanValue}}" />
     {{bookmark.BooleanValue}}
</td>
```

The above shows the text value of bookmark.BooleanValue after the radio button as true but the radio button is not selected.

I don need any complex binding to the viewmodel. The requirement is to make a DB call on selection (which I will get to once I can get the binding sorted

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `ng-value` in conjunction with `ng-model`. `ng-model` specifies the property the radio button is **bound** to and `ng-value` is the **value** given to the bound property when that radio button is selected. See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue).

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
 <td>
<input type="radio" name="{{item.GroupName}}"  ng-model="item.BooleanValue" ng-value="true"/>
     {{item.BooleanValue}}
</td>
```

Comment: Many thanks. I had tried this before but not without removing the placeholders {{}} from around item.BooleanValue

Comment: whenever you do `ng-foo` you don't need the `{{bar}}` round the value.